# 50% + 50% = 100%? Why aren't the <div> aligning?

Tags: html, css

I chrome inspected it, I look into every associated div and I can't see why when I set the two column's width's to 50% each why they won't align next to each other?

I'm guessing there is some sort of default margin or padding. How could I override them if this is the problem?

**css file**

```
.stats-left {
  display: inline-block;
  border : 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}

.stats-right {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  border : 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
}

.count-padding {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: .3em;
  padding-bottom: .3em;
}

.blue-background {
  background-color: #446CB3;
  border : 1px solid black;
}
```

[image]

if I remove the 50% width from both:

[image]

I can't get rid of the white gap between the two blue columns.

**_count.html.erb**

```
<% @user ||= current_user %>
<div class="stats-left">
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.following.count %>
        Following
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.habits.count %>
        Challenges
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.goals.unaccomplished.count %>
        Current
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.quantifieds.count %>
        Tracked
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= following_user_path(@user) %>", id: white>
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.valuations.count %>
        Values
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="stats-right">
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.followers.count %>
        Followers
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.followers.count %>
        Mastered
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.goals.accomplished.count %>
        Accomplished
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="blue-background">
    <a href="<%= followers_user_path(@user) %>">
      <div class="count-padding">
        <%= @user.results.good.count %>
        Good Results
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a gap between inline elements, even when they're `inline-block`.

You can float your elements to the left:

```css
.stats-left,
.stats-right {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* width now includes padding and border */
}
.count-padding {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
}
/* .blue-background { */
.stats-left > div,
.stats-right > div {
    background-color: #446CB3;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mekt103e/

Or do one of the following (both hacks imho).

1) Don't have any spaces between the `inline-block` elements in your markup:

```html
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
```

2) Use comments between them:

```html
<div></div><!--
--><div></div><!--
--><div></div>
```

3) per **@rgthree**, give the container a `font-size: 0;` and then re-set the font size you want for each inline-block element.

The widths don't add up like you think they will because you have a border being added to your 50% width so it's: `50% + border`.  You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to overcome this. When setting a width, `border-box` will calculate it so that 50% width includes and padding or borders you add, `border + padding + ? = 50%`. See CSS above.

Comment: 3) Give the container a `font-size:0px` and then re-set the font size you want for each inline-block element.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that `inline-block` hack!

Answer (score 2):

They are indeed `50%` `width`, but each `div` also has a `1px` border (4 extra `px` in total), so the total width is greater than `100%` :

```
[1px + 50%  + 1px] + [1px + 50% + 1px] > 100%
```

You can use `calc` to calculate the width for each `div`: `width: calc(50% - 2px)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It wasn't the border causing the problem in this case. Hungerstar's answer solved it. Thanks again though.